# Magento2: List translation strings from a module

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate, i18n

In order to build this CSV `app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv`, I want to get an **array** from my module with all the translation-ready strings from all files types (.php, .phtml, .js, .xml).

**.php & .phtml**

```
__('string')
```

**.js**

```
$.mage.__('string')
```

**.xml**

```
<group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="120" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

and

```
<field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="280" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
```

and

```
<argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Report Date</argument>
```

and

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
```

...

How can I get a list (array) of all the translation-ready strings from a module for creating a CSV file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Magento 2 already has a command that can collect all the texts from a certain folder that are translatable.
Since one module can mean 1 folder, let's say your module name is `app/code/Vendor/Module` you can collect all translatable texts like this:

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases app/code/Vendor/Module/ -o app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US_raw.csv
```

Just make sure the folder `i18n` exists inside your module.
After you are done translating what you need to move the file `en_US_raw.csv` to a file name corresponding to your language code inside the same folder.
For Romanian, for example, the file name should be `ro_RO.csv`.

Comment: Hey @Marius, I Update my question, sorry for my first question, I hope so as well now my question.

Comment: It works perfectly