# Magento 2 Translate Modules for a theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, localisation, language

I want to translate terms from various magento modules for a custom-theme (based un Luma).

What I've been doing:

1. Created a list of translation terms `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv` looking like this:

   ```
   "Search entire store here...", 
   Produktsuche",module,Magento_Search
   "Sort By",Sortieren,module,Magento_Catalog
   "Shop By",Filter,module,Magento_Catalog
   ```
2. Then I tried various commands but all fail to deploy the translation finally to my **development** shop:

   ```
   magento i18n:pack /path/to/csv de_DE
   ```

   Does something, but I don't know what. I says `Successfully saved de_DE language package.` but not telling the secret of **where to**.
3. Also I ran

   ```
   magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
   ```

   Wich results in:

   ```
   [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]                                                         
   NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.               
   In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.           
   If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f'
   ```

   Running

   ```
   magento setup:upgrade
   ```

   Not showing any results.
   I also failed to find a good guideline explaining how to translate **module based** terms on a theme basis.

   **Can someone point out how to translate module strings to another language on a theme basis**

Answer (score 0):

You can try from above link, after that you can use your point 3.

[Magento2: List translation strings from a module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195726/magento2-list-translation-strings-from-a-module)

Comment: That explains it only for a module, not for a theme. Also, my theme does not contain so many translateable terms. As you can see above, the terms are from module,Magento_Catalog so it won't find them. I also did the collect-phrases -m option to gather all the terms.That works well but the file won't apply if I put it to `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the following command

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

I had the same problem in my Greek eshop.