# get translated string Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, translate

In Magento1 we can get translated string by

> _getTranslatedString() from app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php

but in Magento2 there is not such methods. Is there any alternative method available for this?

Comment: What you want to translate?

Comment: I want to translate string :)

Comment: I mean you want to translate simply `string` in `phtml` for different language?

Comment: I need to log all translated string in my custom file . In Magento 1 I can do it with just calling `_getTranslatedString()` method so I am looking same method in Magento 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not more knowledge about `Magento 1` and `_getTranslatedString()` function but as per your query this might be help to you.

Magento 2 already has a command that can collect all the texts from a certain folder that are translatable.

Since one module can mean 1 folder, let's say your module name is `app/code/Vendor/Module` you can collect all translatable texts like this:

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases app/code/Vendor/Module/ -o app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US_raw.csv
```

Just make sure the folder i18n exists inside your module.

For more details [Check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195726/magento2-list-translation-strings-from-a-module)

Comment: Yes, it can collect the only original words not translatable and I am looking for translatable word. For ex. "Hi" and in csv file it has "hello" then it should return "hello"